# PyQtGraph: stop execution without process manager

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to use the module *pyqtgraph* in **python** to plot some real time data but the program stucks in the plot, I mean, once I close the plot window the program doesn't stop running and I have to kill it using process manager.

Even with a simple code such as this one, the same happens

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Graphic")
p = win.addPlot(title="Graphic")
curva= p.plot(pen='y')
p.setRange(yRange=[-120, 120])
curva.setData([0,20,40,80],[0,20,40,10])
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

(I found this code sample in *Laboratorio Gluón* blog while searching for information of the module)

I think the problem is the last command but it is necessary to display the data. I tried writting `pg.QtGui.QApplication.quit()` right after the `exec_()` but I got nothing different...

Is there any way to stop it "automatically" or detect that the window has been closed?
Thank u in advance

**NOTE:** I am running the code using Spyder

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: @eyllanesc running the script in spyder

Comment: See https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, though thank you

Answer (score 0):

Qt should automatically exit once all of its windows have closed. The example you posted works fine if I run it from a command line.

As eyllanesc pointed out in the comments, spyder is known to interfere with some Qt operation if it is not configured correctly.

Comment: I just tried to run the script from Windoes console, but my program crashed once I close the window of the plot. Other times, it neven opened (ir opened "not responding").